# Upgrade to latest version of libexiv2

Tags: libraries, versions

To get an update lens db, I need a newer version of libexiv2 than is currently in the repo. Specifically I need version 0.27 or later. I tried to build it from source, and installed it in /usr/local. Now I want Darktable to find the new version. Tried

`sudo ldconfig`

And modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it still loads the old version. Should I download a new Darktable too, and compile that against the new version or would replacing the symlink be sufficient.

Comment: why not uninstall v 0.25 then make install 0.27

Comment: @cmak.fr This will also remove all other packages that are dependent on libexiv2